# Woocommerce: display crossed price for free products

Tags: woocommerce

I can't display crossed price for 0 priced variable products.
That is my code. Where I'm going wrong ?

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_including_tax_html', 'woocommerce_get_regular_price_html', 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'price_free_zero_empty', 9998, 2 );

function price_free_zero_empty( $price, $product ){
    if ( '' === $product->get_price_including_tax() || 0 == $product->get_price_including_tax() ) {
$regular_price = $product->get_price_including_tax(); 
        $price = '<del>' . wc_price( $regular_price ) . '</del> '. '<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">'.__("Free", "woocommerce").'</span>';
        
      }
    return $price;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function wpglorify_price_free_zero_empty( $price, $product ) {
    if ( $product->get_price() == 0 ) {
        if ( $product->is_on_sale() && $product->get_regular_price() ) {
            $regular_price = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'qty' => 1, 'price' => $product->get_regular_price() ) );

            $price = wc_format_price_range( '<del>' . wc_price($regular_price) . '</del>', __( 'Omaggio!', 'woocommerce' ) );
        } else {
            $price = '<span class="amount">' . __( 'Omaggio!', 'woocommerce' ) . '</span>';
        }
    }

    return $price;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'wpglorify_price_free_zero_empty', 10, 2 );
```